# What decides what constrains to use when creating table from a physical schema

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning SQL and going trough some lab exercises when i got to a question that asks to create table from a physical schema. No problem there, simple enough to create a table, but i got it wrong because i didn't use the `NOT NULL`, `NULL`, and `FK`constraints. So what in this schema tells me what constrains to use? Here is the correct answer according to the exercise.  (the auto increment was provided in the question)

`CREATE TABLE customerorder (DonutOrderID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,` 
`CustomerID INT(11) NOT NULL,` 
`DonutOrderTimestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),` 
`SpecialNotes VARCHAR(500) NULL,` 
`FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID));`

[image: schema]

Comment: Typically domain knowledge.

Comment: I suspect that the ER diagram symbols next to each column and the line shapes connecting the entities are consistent and give that information.

Comment: That was my first though too, but upon googling, i have not found a schema that uses that style icons or has explanation for the use of those icons,

Comment: From a cursory glance it looks like the primary key has a key symbol. Primary keys can't be null. The solid green diamonds are columns that can't be null. The white diamonds with green outline are columns that can be null. The purple diamonds are columns that are foreign keys. Foreign keys can't be null. The dotted crowfoot lines represent one-to-many relationships between entities. (DonutOrderTimestamp has a default value, so it can't be null).

Comment: Yes, the symbols help. But the statement that foreign keys can't be null is not true.

Comment: Yes, foreign keys CAN be null. I just can't remember the last time I implemented null foreign keys. Definitely a domain thing.

Answer (score 3):

1. A `customerorder` without a customer makes no sense, so its customer ID column should not be nullable.
2. A `customerorder` must refer to an existing customer, so you should make the customer ID a foreign key to the customer table.
3. `SpecialNotes` are only special when they are optional in my opinion, so the should be nullable.
4. If the table is called `customerorder`, its ID should not be called `DonutOrderID`, as this name looks somewhat unrelated and I'd expect some additional `DonutOrder` table in the database. The customerorder's ID should be called `id` or `customerorder_id` or the like instead.
5. As a customer order seems to be a donat order in that database, the `DonutOrderTimestamp` should probably be obligatory (i.e. not nullable), as every order is placed at some point in time.

Comment: From what i gather then, it seems it is up to judgement to decide what constrains to use, i was thinking/hoping there was a hard and fast rule to follow.